# How many free variables has the Reshitikhin-Turaev polynomial for trivalent graphs colored with the adjoint?

Tags: rt.representation-theory, graph-theory

For the moment, forget that you know anything about Lie algebras. Just assume that you have lots of trivalent graphs and you may simplify them
a) with the IHX relation, b) with crossing two legs over a node gives a minus sign, and the usual treatment of virtual crossings, c) by reducing faces of size 1,2,3 the usual way and assuming that two disjoint graphs give their product. (Works for *any* semisimple Lie algebra.)
By experimenting up to 12 nodes, I found that all (EDIT: only the "rational", i.e. the merge of two 4-tangles with 6 nodes each, this excludes Peterson etc.) graphs may be expressed in the value of the loop o, of the cube c and of the hexagonal prisma (18j symbol B). But since I know of the Thurston paper that considered far higher graphs to prove that the F4 and E6 family have only finitely many members, I wouldn't be surprised at all if work has been done on this, or even B=polynomial(o,c) holds.
Any news for me before I use brute force as always? :-)

Comment: Have you read the preprints by Vogel?

Comment: Yes, but what use is the Vogel plane when your Lie algebra is, say, A1*F4? I want to check what would come after the Vogel plane, if any. (Also, it's written in Math :-)

Comment: You would get a better response if you learnt to read and write Math.